# $\{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \sin(nx)\}_{n\ge 1}\cup \{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \cos((n+\frac 12)x)\}_{n\ge 0}$ is an orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis

I want to show that $A:=\{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \sin(nx)\}_{n\ge 1}\cup \{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \cos((n+\frac 12)x)\}_{n\ge 0}$ is a orthonormal basis for $L^2[-\pi,\pi]$.

To show that this is an orthonormal set I can just calculate integrals (and using the symmetric property of odd functions).
Now, I know that $B:=\{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \sin(nx)\}_{n\ge 1}\cup \{\frac 1{\sqrt \pi} \cos(nx)\}_{n\ge 1}\cup\{\frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\}$ is a orthonormal basis for this space. So if will show that $\text {span}\{\cos((n+\frac 12)x)\}_{n\ge 0}\}=\text {span}\{\{\cos(nx)\}_{n\ge 1}\}\cup \{\frac 1{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\}\}$ the proof will be complete?

And by the way, why does the constant function is in the basis $B$? Isn't it in the span of the even functions anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $\{ \sin(nx)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ form an orthonormal basis of $L^2[0,\pi]$. These can be divided into
$$
         \sin(2nx), n=1,2,3,\cdots \\
         \sin((2n+1)x), n=0,1,2,3,\cdots
$$
By shifting $x$ by $\pi/2$, a new set is obtained on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$.
\begin{align}
         \sin(2n(x+\pi/2))&=(-1)^n\sin(2nx) \\
      \sin((2n+1)(x+\pi/2))&=\sin((2n+1)x+n\pi+\pi/2)\\
         &=(-1)^n\cos((2n+1)x)
\end{align}
Finally, the full set on $[-\pi,\pi]$ consists of elements
$$
          \sin(nx),\cos((n+1/2)x).
$$